# ubuntu 16.04 owner rights

Tags: permissions

I have a brand new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP stream 11-001nd. It's the only OS on installed without any partitions.

Now I want to create `/etc/pm/config.d/config`.

I clicked on the right mouse button to select new document. This appears to be not selectable. So I went to properties, permissions, and there is shown at the bottom of that window, `You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions`.

Well, if I'm not the owner, who is? How can I change this so I'll be able to create that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are (at least) *two* users in any Ubuntu installation**. Both are in *your* control.

The two are

- Your user
- `root` user - Linux equivalent of administrator account. Has all powers. Handles administrative tasks.

Now, *your* user only has access to your personal files. All other files, which are essential configuration and system files, are owned by `root`.

**How do I access them?**

The `root` account can only (unless you willingly workaround this) is by using `sudo`. `sudo` is the program that allows normal users (like you) to run programs with powers of the administrative `root` user.

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksudo nautilus` in it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A dialog asking for a password will appear. Enter *your* password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or Click *OK*.

The file manager should open, but this time it is run with `root`'s powers. You can now do anything, including creating that file.

***Why* are there two accounts if I can access it anyway?**

Privilege separation — the idea that you should only get the power to do/destroy anything when you *need* it. A major contributor to Linux's excellent reputation for security is due to the fact that it separates admin from user.

If you would run as `root` all the time, any virus could destroy your system very easily.

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned folder is owned by `root`, so you should create and edit the file as root. To achieve that, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

> gksu gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config

You will be prompted for root password.

If you are familiar with terminal, you can easily create the file with command

> sudo nano /etc/pm/config.d/config

(substitute nano with your favorite text editor)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
su administrator
```

"Enter root password of admin"

```
cd "path of the file"

sudo gedit "filename"
```

Root is the equivalent default super user to administrator. As your standard account does not have permission, you have to switch back to administrator or root user. `su` command will switch the username passed as a root user.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you don't own the file.
To get access to file just do the following.

1. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   $sudo -s
   ```
2. Type the administrator password.
3. Then do, (don't forget to substitute the *username*)

   ```
   $cd /home/[username]/.config
   $chmod 777 opera
   ```